# Localizar arquivo usando Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou com uma duvida, como localizar um arquivo utilizando python. O objetivo é localizar um arquivo dentro de um diretório e retornar todo o caminho do diretorio onde se encontra o arquivo e caso nao encontre o arquivo, retornar None.
Eu criei o codigo abaixo, mas ele retorna todos os diretorios que nao contem o arquivo e tambem o diretorio que contem o arquivo. Alguem pode verificar se esta correto ou esqueci algo? Thanks!

```
import os

diret = "/"
filename = "teste"

def achar_arq():

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(diret):

    if filename in files:
        print(os.path.join(roots,filename))
    if filename not in files:
        print('None')

print(achar_arq())
```

Comment: A busca precisa ser recursiva em todos os diretórios filhos? Se sim, o que deve acontecer se for encontrado mais de um arquivo com este mesmo nome?

Comment: Deve retornar todos os diretorios que contenham um arquivo com este mesmo nome, mas apenas estes, ou seja, ou retorna os diretorios que tenham o arquivo ou retorna apena um None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da versão 3.4 do Python não há mais justificativas¹ para se utilizar a biblioteca `os` para se manipular diretórios e arquivos, pois nesta versão foi adicionada a biblioteca `pathlib`, que abstrai as funções da `os` em uma API bem mais simples de se utilizar.

Para criar um objeto que representa um diretório basta fazer:

```
diretorio = pathlib.Path('diretorio')
```

E para buscar todos os arquivos com o nome `teste` dentro deste diretório basta fazer:

```
arquivos = diretorio.glob('**/teste')
```

O `**` indica que o arquivo poderá estar em qualquer nível de sub-diretórios, não apenas na raiz.

Para uma estrutura de diretórios semelhantes a:

```
└ diretorio/
.   └ arquivos/
.   .   └ arquivos/
.   .   .   └ banana
.   .   .   └ teste
.   .   └ teste
.   └ teste
```

Bastaria fazer:

```py
diretorio = pathlib.Path('diretorio')
arquivos = diretorio.glob('**/teste')

for arquivo in arquivos:
    print(arquivo)
```

A saída seria:

```
arquivos/teste
arquivos/arquivos/teste
arquivos/arquivos/arquivos/teste
```

Vale citar que o retorno de `glob` será um objeto iterável de instâncias de `pathlib.PosixPath`, caso queira pesquisar como manipular tais objetos.

<sup>1) Há, mas na grande maioria dos casos a biblioteca `pathlib` pode ser utilizada</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Mas uma duvida, caso minha versao nao seja essa, a resposta que forneci teria o erro onde?